# HTTP ERROR : 405(This page isn't working) When I Refresh The Page(ASP.Net Core MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on an ASP.Net Core MVC website where I have a page with datatable which has a button for every record which leads to further details of that record. When I click that details button, it works fine but when I refresh the details page, I encounter the above mentioned error. There are no any debugging errors as per my knowledge. Please help me out!!

Here is the code for the page with the datatable :

```
@model Derawala.Models.ViewModels.ParentForApply

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<form method="post">
   
      <div class="container p-3">

        <div class="row pt-4">
            <div class="col-6">
                <h2 class="text-success">Application List</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        @if (Model.AppList.Any())
        {
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover align-middle table-bordered table table-striped" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Applicant Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Contact No
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Institute Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Institute Contact
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var obj in Model.AppList)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center text-primary" style="font-weight:bold;">@obj.FirstName</td>
                            <td class="text-center text-primary" style="font-weight:bold;">@obj.Contact</td>
                            <td class="text-center text-primary" style="font-weight:bold;">@obj.Institute</td>
                            <td class="text-center text-primary" style="font-weight:bold;">@obj.InstCnt</td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                                    <button type="submit" asp-action="Details" asp-route-Id="@obj.Id" class="btn btn-primary mx-2">
                                        <i class="fas fa-list"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-Id="@obj.Id" class="btn btn-danger mx-2">
                                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>No Application Exists!</p>
        }
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the view of page with the datatable
[image]
When I click on the **Details** button(blue button), it leads to the details page shown below :
Here is the code for the Details Page :

```
@model Derawala.Models.ViewModels.ParentForApply
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="@Model.Apply.PofId" hidden />
    <div class="container backgroundWhite pt-4">
        <div class="card" style="border:1px solid #000000; ">
            @*<div class="card-header bg-dark text-light ml-0 row container" style="border-radius: 0px;">*@
            <div class="card-header" style="background-color:black;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 align-self-start">
                        <h1 class="text-white">@Model.Apply.FirstName&nbsp;@Model.Apply.LastName</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 align-self-end">
                        <h1 class="text-warning">Application Id :@Model.Apply.AppId</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="container rounded p-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 p-1 text-center">
                            <img src="@WC.ImagePath[0]@Model.Apply.Photo" class="rounded w-25" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
                            <div class="row pl-3">

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <span class="badge p-3 border" style="background-color:lightpink">@Model.Apply.Qualification</span>
                                    <span class="badge p-3 border" style="background-color:lightskyblue">@Model.Apply.BankName</span>
                                    <h3 class="text-success"></h3>

                                    <p class="text-secondary">@Model.Apply.Description</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row pl-3">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    Download Id Proof : <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" asp-route-id="@Model.Apply.PofId" asp-action="DownloadFile">Download</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer bg-dark">
                <div class="row">
                   
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 ">
                        
                    <a asp-action="RemoveFromCart" class="btn btn-primary btn-square form-control btn-lg" style="height:50px;">Donate Now <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-medical"></i></a> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

                    <button type="submit" asp-action="" class="btn btn-danger form-control btn-lg" style="height:50px;">Delete This Application <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the view of details page :
[image]
and when I refresh this details page it gives me this HTTP 405 error :
[image]

Comment: Checking the [http status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors) you got it says "_A request method is not supported for the requested resource; for example, a GET request on a form that requires data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a read-only resource._"

Comment: Pls post the detail actions. "Post" and "Get " if you have both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your  Details action probably has [HttpPost] attribute and you call it using your submit button. But when you are trying to refresh the browser calls Get method. So you have to remove  [HttpPost] from the details action, or create another one with  [HttpGet].

Comment: You are very welcome!